# Can I do it through Repeated Measures ANCOVA? If so, how can I interpret the results?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, ancova

I'd like to have some help, please. I'm writing my masters and I have a huge doubt about which test should I use. What I want to measure is: the effect of therapy on people who have and don't have childhood trauma (two groups), having years of schooling as a covariate. There are 3 times in measurement: baseline, 10th session and post-intervention (continuous variables); a dichotomous variable (having or not having trauma) as dependent; and another dichotomous variable as covariate (until 8 years of schooling and 9 years or more) because I need to adjust to this. I'm trying it through GLM on SPSS (repeated measures ancova), but I can't find how to analyze it, which values to consider, and worse: if it's correct to do it this way. My last question is: the sample of people who have and don't have trauma aren't equal. Is it a problem? Thank you so much for the attention! I'm running out of time and I don't know where else to look for help.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a multilevel model. Your dependent variable is whatever it is. If that variable is continuous, then I'd look at linear MLMs, if it is categorical, then a nonlinear MLM.   Your IVs are then time and group and education and probably the interaction of time and group. Your random variable is person.

Also, I would not dichotomize education.

I don't use SPSS so I can't offer advice on that..